# Fabric by twitter: Read-only permissions for an Android app

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm using twitter login for my app - I followed the tutorial from this link: https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android.
It creates a new project at https://fabric.io/.
It works fine but it asks the user for Read/Write permissions when I need only the read permission.

I know that I can change the pemissions at https://apps.twitter.com/ (Twitter's application management), I don't see my app there, but I can see it at fabric's app managment.

Does some of you know how can I change the permissions?[image: Twitter login screen]

Comment: +1 This drives me crazy. My app requires read permissions only (and write permissions freak out users, in general) and I can't get it done with Fabric.

Comment: Can you create the app manually on the Twitter side and use those keys?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as you normally set permissions. Once you create your app at http://apps.twitter.com/, click on the details tab of your app and go to the "Applications Settings" heading. From there you can click "modify app permissions" under the Access level and, well, modify your access levels. Below is a screenshot of what you're looking for.

[image: Screen Shot of Twitter App Panel]

> I know that I can change the pemissions at https://apps.twitter.com/
>   (Twitter's application management), I don't see my app there, but I
>   can see it at fabric's app management.

Fabric auto-generates credentials by default. To prevent that "If you’re not using Fabric’s auto-generated Twitter credentials, ensure that “Allow this application to be used to Sign in to Twitter” is checked for your Twitter app before using this feature."

Source: https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter-login

Answer (score 0):

Logon to fabric.io and you should be able to find your app, along with option to edit the permissions.